# Can Survey123 have a select_one create another respective select_one that repeats

Tags: select, arcgis-survey123

Per boss's request, I need to make a survey that is broken into 3 different Test Well sections, where each Test Well has an associating list of Monitoring Wells. Basically, field tech will choose the Test Well 1 and fill out a few sections of different field measurements. After they fill out that info, they need to go to each Monitoring Well associated with Test Well 1 and fill out more field measurements. So which Test Well they are working on determines what Monitoring Wells will appear in the survey.

Originally, I thought about just creating 3 separate groups within one survey (Test Well 1, Test Well 2, Test Well 3) and then within each group will be its respective Monitoring Well options, but I am worried about how that may export to AGOL and Excel (I wouldn't want one long, continuous row of data each time the survey is submitted, I would want the excel sheet breaking it up into 3 separate rows or sheets.

I was trying to figure out a way to use pulldata() or begin repeat or if, then statements to set this survey up, but I haven't been able to figure out how to have a select_one TestWell lead to select_one Monitoring Well respective to that Test Well and not all 3 Test Wells.

Is the best way just to do 3 separate surveys and then do begin repeat with pulldata() from an excel file?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the items in `select_one Monitoring Well` based on value of `select_one TestWell`.

In the `choices` tab of the xls form add a new column, give it a name, say "filtervalue" and for each Monitoring Well add the name of the associated Test Well:[image]

Then on the "survey" tab add an expression like `filtervalue=${TestWell}` in the `choice_filter` column for the `select_one Monitoring Well` question:[image]

The choices in the repeat are filtered for the selected Test Well:[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly